# Combine rows in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to make new DataFrame (or update this one). How? 
If user have 'Date_start' in one row = 'Date_end + 1 second' in another row, it should be combine into one row. So, using below dataframe for first user XXX I want combine first 3 rows into one.
Also this operation should be done only if user and his Dates are in same group.

```
      Group   Date      User    Date_start            Date_end
1       A   2018-09-20  XXX 2018-09-20 00:01:35 2018-09-20 00:59:59
2       A   2018-09-20  XXX 2018-09-20 01:00:00 2018-09-20 01:59:59
3       A   2018-09-20  XXX 2018-09-20 02:00:00 2018-09-20 02:18:10
4       A   2018-09-20  XXY 2018-09-20 00:00:19 2018-09-20 00:59:59
5       A   2018-09-20  XXY 2018-09-20 01:00:00 2018-09-20 01:09:26
6       B   2018-09-20  XXZ 2018-09-20 00:28:39 2018-09-20 00:59:59
... ... ... ... ... ...
1999996 A   2018-09-20  ZZX 2018-09-20 00:00:08 2018-09-20 00:59:59
1999997 B   2018-09-20  ZZX 2018-09-20 01:00:00 2018-09-20 01:59:59
1999998 A   2018-09-20  ZZY 2018-09-20 00:04:22 2018-09-20 00:59:59
1999999 B   2018-09-20  ZZZ 2018-09-20 00:00:54 2018-09-20 00:59:59
2000000 A   2018-09-20  ZZZ 2018-09-20 01:00:00 2018-09-20 01:59:59
```

Here's what should be for user XXX (3 first rows combined into one):

```
1       A   2018-09-20  XXX 2018-09-20 00:01:35 2018-09-20 02:18:10
```

Comment: are the date_start and date_end stored in string format?

Comment: also ```Date_start in one row = Date_end + 1 second in another row,``` is not clear. please elaborate What I understood is that the date should remain same and thats it.

Comment: Yes, it's string format.

Comment: U can see that date_end in first row is 00:59:59 so it's one second less than second date_start, so then it should be combine into one row. Same thing is with second date_end and third date_start, it also should be combined into one row.

Comment: Are the entry sorted according to ```Date_end```

Comment: No, they're not sorted. Also, there're more groups than just A and it's also not sorted by group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this can be done using `groupby`.  First, I converted the times fro string to datetime:

```
df['Date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_start'])
df['Date_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_end'])
```

Second, make a function to `apply` with the `groupby` operation.  We will group by the `User` and `Group` to combine their times:

```
def mygroup(d):
    out = d.iloc[0, :]                    # take the first row of each group
    x = df.columns.get_loc('Date_end')    # get iloc position of date_end
    out.loc['Date_end']  = d.iloc[-1, x]  # replace the first rows date_end with that of the last row
    return out
```

Finally, `apply` the function and reset the index:

```
df = df.groupby(['Group', 'User']).apply(mygroup).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output for the first 5 rows:

```
  Group        Date User          Date_start            Date_end
0     A  2018-09-20  XXX 2018-09-20 00:01:35 2018-09-20 02:18:10
1     A  2018-09-20  XXY 2018-09-20 00:00:19 2018-09-20 01:09:26
```

Note this is not utilizing "1 second before" aspect that you mention.  I suppose this would be a problem if for each `User` & `Group` combination, there are more than one series of times that you want get grouped.  In that case, this approach could still be used if there was an extra step to create a new column which labels each segment of time to be grouped - which may not be the simplest operation but should be possible.